# Navigation returns to same page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to navigate to another screen in flutter. However, the navigation starts the animation as usual and then returns to the same screen. The code works perfectly fine on iOS and everywhere else in the app.
Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.
This is the code I used to navigate:
WHERE I AM TRYING TO NAVIGATE TO

```
class PravUI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PravUIState createState() => _PravUIState();
}



class _PravUIState extends State<PravUI> {
  var data;
  bool connectivity = true;
  StreamSubscription<DataConnectionStatus> listener;

  Timer timer;
  int counter = 0;

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    notificationPlugin
        .setListenerForLowerVersions(onNotificationInLowerVersions);
    notificationPlugin.setOnNotificationClick(onNotificationClick);
    _firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('TestTopic');

        _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        await notificationPlugin.showNotification(message['notification']['title'],message['notification']['body']);
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        if(message['data']['link'] == null){
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PravUI()));
        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UrlViewers(message['data']['link'])));
        }
        
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        print("Parse: ${message['data']['link']}");
        if(message['data']['link'] == null){
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PravUI()));
        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UrlViewers(message['data']['link'])));
        }
      },
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));

    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("Push Messaging token: $token");
    });
    
    data = getData();
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 25), (Timer t) => addValue(connectivity));

  }
  Future<dynamic> receivedPushNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
  }

  onNotificationInLowerVersions(ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) {
    print('Notification Received ${receivedNotification.id}');
  }
  onNotificationClick(String payload) {
    print('Payload $payload');
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (coontext) {
      return NotificationScreen(
        payload: payload,
      );
    }));
  }

  @override

  void addValue(bool connectivity){
    if(connectivity == true) {
      setState(() {
        data = getData();
        counter++;
      });
      print("Counter: $counter");
    }
    else
      print("No connection");


  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    timer?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var icons = [Icons.home];
    var texts = ["Home"];
    return Scaffold(
```

WHERE I AM NAVIGATING FROM

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
          title: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: Row(

              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back), onPressed: (){
                      //Navigator.pop(context);
                      //Navigator.pushReplacement(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new PravUI()));
                      //Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PravUI()));
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => PravUI()));
                    }),
```

GIVEN MESSAGE

```
onLaunch: {notification: {}, data: {collapse_key: com.myapp.Name, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1612992084297, 
google.delivered_priority: high, link: http://pravachakasabdam.com/index.php/site/news/15482, google.ttl: 2419200, from: /topics/TestTopic, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:1612992084608255%465f258b465f258b}}
I/flutter (29560): Push Messaging token: dWGNRiEETT64C6fqLcnTqt:APA91bHKbsPcpcfw7Rh4tKVGKg1slCXZ9_M-f9EnJCcL0uxPLbbY0IvHand2L6eJGBUYKXVsWokqEg-J4ocNlZxkSuOfgZX65Qk8TPEvS2ojqzuKKM-Ya0quXffTd4esUDxeoSJpyzc5
I/HwPhoneWindow(29560): updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=0, mNavBarShow=false, mIsFloating=false
I/HwPhoneWindow(29560): updateLayoutParamsColor true mSpecialSet=true, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=fffcfcfc, mNavBarShow=false, mIsFloating=false
D/OpenGLRenderer(29560):   HWUI Binary is  enabled
D/HwAppInnerBoostImpl(29560): asyncReportData com.myapp.Name,2,1,2,0 interval=710
W/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor(29560): depended package hiTouch does n't exist!
I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor(29560): HiTouch restricted: system app HiTouch don't exist.
D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector(29560): onAttached, package=com.myapp.Name, windowType=2030, mHiTouchRestricted=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(29560):   HWUI Binary is  enabled
E/ion     (29560): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/ion     (29560): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
```

Comment: which widget holds this `build`?

Comment: @theiskaa  PravUI is the name of the class

Comment: @TirthPatel I'm not too sure what you mean, sorry